# What's the most efficient way to handle displaying a dialog/modal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, dom-events, mouseevent, mousemove

[UPDATE:] here is a link to test (if you don't want to clone the repo) http://jsfiddle.net/integralist/g9EPu/

I've got a lot of dialogs/modals that need to be displayed when mousing over certain links in a web app.

### Table of content (tl;dr)

- How I used to do handle it
- How I've tried it recently
- Which is better?
- What about mouseenter/leave?

### How I used to do handle it

The way I usually do this is to use event delegation.

So I add one event handler to a container and then check for the relevant element to become the target and then display the relevant dialog.

I normally have one dialog which I change the content for and re-position (saves having lots of different HTML mark-up).

If the `mouseover` event (for the link) gets triggered then I display the dialog.

If the `mouseout` event (for the link) gets triggered then I hide the dialog.

If I `mouseout` of the link which triggered the event handler then I normally need to set a timer to delay hiding the dialog (just long enough) so I can then mouseover the dialog which itself clears the timer set by the `mouseout` of the link.

I then have a `mouseout` event bound to the dialog so I can then hide the dialog when the user rolls their mouse off the dialog.

There are two problems I've encountered at this stage, the first happens practically all the time and the other is an edge case I noticed recently which prompted me to try and find a better solution...

1. The dialog has 'x' number of child elements and rolling the mouse over a child element causes the `mouseout` event for the dialog to be triggered hence I need to put in checks to see if the element has a parent which is the dialog itself and if so then don't try to hide the dialog.
2. When using this technique on a <table> element I've found that when the mouse moves too quickly the mouseout/over events don't get triggered.

### How I've tried it recently

For example code see: https://github.com/Integralist/Mouse-Over-Out-Script (you should be able to just clone the repo and run the index.html file locally to see what's happening)

But to give a brief explanation...

We bind a `mousemove` event to the `document.documentElement` element (but you could do it on the document.body if you wanted) and then we store the x/y co-ordinates of the mouse position. We provide public API access to a 'check' method which lets us know if the position of the mouse is over the element we've provided to 'check' (we measure the elements dimensions and add those onto its x/y co-ordinates).

In the above repo we have a calendar which shows a dialog whenever a particular date has an event on. We're storing all <td>'s that have an event and we set-up a timer for each of those <td>'s (this is because we need to keep calling the 'check' method to see if that <td> has the mouse over it).

So potentially there could be 31+ (because we're showing the first few days of the following month) opportunities for a dialog to be shown and so 31+ timers set!

This example repo works now, where as the first version where I was using event delegation wasn't.

### Which is better?

I'm worried about performance on the `mousemove` version because it can potentially use a lot of timers (depending on how many dialogs you need in a single page). In my calendar example above there is up to 31+ timers that could be running!

### What about mouseenter/leave?

I know these events exist and if all browsers supported it then I could safely use the first version and not have to check for child elements causing erroneous mouseout/over events to be triggered. But regardless I don't believe this would have fixed the example with the event calendar where moving the mouse too quickly was meaning the mouseout/over events for the <td>'s weren't being triggered by the browser. Either way, I know you can polyfill this as jQuery provides mouseenter/leave events but looking through their code I couldn't get that to work for my script (as I don't use jQuery or any other general purpose library - ps, and I don't wish to, so please do not suggest that as an option).

Many thanks for any help/advice or guidance someone can provide me.

Comment: Rather than asking us to make local copies of your file to test out the problem why don't you set it up for us on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Updated with link, but here it is again in case you missed it:http://jsfiddle.net/integralist/g9EPu/

Comment: Can you restructure your HTML? If the given events section/div element is a child of its associated calendar date element that would make your mouseover event management simpler. If you can't change the HTML before your JS runs, would you consider changing it after to achieve the same end?

Comment: @thisgeek I've purposely used one popup <div id="dialog-event"> to handle all events because the alternative is to have 31+ popup elements (with all their HTML) loaded into the page which will increase the page weight to an unacceptable level (imo).

Answer (score 0):

> The dialog has 'x' number of child elements and rolling the mouse over a child element causes the mouseout event for the dialog to be triggered hence I need to put in checks to see if the element has a parent which is the dialog itself and if so then dont try to hide the dialog.

To solve this: in your event code, simply use the function "isAncestor" (see below)

```
/*
 * element = the "target" in your mouseout event handler
 * other = the node you really want to check if you're over
 */
isAncestor: function(element, other)
{
    while ( element && element != other ) element = element.parentNode;
    return ( element != null && element != undefined );
}
```

So in your mouseout code for your element (let's call it "itemElement"), you'd check it like:

```
//We're really mousing out, close dialog
if ( !isAncestor( mouseOutEvent.target, itemElement ) )
{
    ...do something ...
}
```

Comment: This would work OK for when binding a mouse over/out event for each individual <td> that had a class of 'has-events' but it doesn't work when using event delegation (e.g. binding a single event to the table element and then checking if the moused over element is a td with a class of 'has-events').

Comment: For example, if i use event delegation then when I roll my mouse over a td with a class of 'has-events' then fine it shows the dialog, but if I then move my mouse slightly I could end up moving over a child element of that td which causes a mouseout event of the td and then a mouseover event on the child element. Using your isAncestor function I have no way to tell it which td is the one I'm really checking mouse out for (without storing a reference to it).

Comment: `I have no way to tell it which td is the one I'm really checking mouse out for (without storing a reference to it)` No, it's actually quite simple. When a mouseout is triggered, simply check that the target's ancestor has "has-events". If it does, then you quitely cancel/silence the mouseout event.

Comment: By the way, your suggestion almost works but not quite when the user moves too quickly out from an element as the mouseout event doesn't trigger (or pickup the mouseover on the next element). See http://jsfiddle.net/PA2SY/ for an example.

Comment: Also, this discussion has digressed slightly from one of my original points which was "2. When using this technique [i.e. event delegation] on a <table> element I've found that when the mouse moves too quickly the mouseout/over events don't get triggered" - hence why I went with the mousemove attempt instead. As it seems the last example using your isAncestor() function suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @Integralist No, that's not the problem. The problem is your code. When I tried your example but added in some extra code to show that mouseout is indeed called (despite the popup not hiding) it showed it IS being called. So the problem is with your targets. You need to do some more bug testing and print out every call along with the identity of every target from each event AND every child target iterated over in the isAncestor function.